# Same bash script involving grep succeeds on one machine but fails on another

Tags: regex, bash, grep, gitlab, moto

I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Calls AWS CloudFormation and creates the stack
STACKNAME="bootstrapStack"
TEMPLATEBODY=file://\$PWD/templates/bootstrapStack.yml
TEMPLATEVERSION=v0.1.0-alpha

if $( aws $AWSENDPOINTPARAM cloudformation describe-stacks --output text | grep -Eq "$STACKNAME" )
then 
    # output of above was similar to:
    # STACKS  2010-07-27T22:28:28Z    False   arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789:stack/bootstrapStack/16766dc5-75c9-4e3f-b4cf-7814d7fbbc6f      bootstrapStack  CREATE_COMPLETE
    # OUTPUTS TemplatesBucket dw-cloudformation-templates
    # PARAMETERS      TemplateVersion v0.1.0-alpha

    aws $AWSENDPOINTPARAM cloudformation update-stack \
        --template-body $TEMPLATEBODY \
        --stack-name $STACKNAME \
        --parameters "ParameterKey=TemplateVersion,ParameterValue=$TEMPLATEVERSION" \
        $*
else
    aws $AWSENDPOINTPARAM cloudformation create-stack \
        --template-body $TEMPLATEBODY \
        --stack-name $STACKNAME \
        --parameters "ParameterKey=TemplateVersion,ParameterValue=$TEMPLATEVERSION" \
        $*
fi
```

I wrote some unit tests for the above script using `shunit2` and `moto_server`. Here is the test script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Unit test for the deploy script of the stack

SCRIPT_UNDER_TEST=./scripts/createStack.sh
# set up
oneTimeSetUp(){
    if [[ ! -d "./test-logs" ]]
    then
        mkdir ./test-logs
    fi
}

setUp(){
    ( moto_server cloudformation >>test-logs/moto_server.log 2>&1 ) &
    export AWSENDPOINTPARAM=--endpoint="http://localhost:5000"
    sleep 5
}

match_stack_output(){
    # example match:
    # arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789:stack/bootstrapStack/2f255d54-f426-46b6
    assertTrue "Output Pattern does not match" \
        '$( \
            cat test_log | \
            grep -Eq \
                "^arn:aws:cloudformation:[[:alpha:]]{2}[-](east|west|south|north)-[[:digit:]]:[[:digit:]]*:stack\/bootstrapStack\/[[:alnum:]]*(-[[:alnum:]]*)*$" \
        )'
}

test_createStack(){
    . $SCRIPT_UNDER_TEST --output text >test_log

    match_stack_output
}

test_updateStack(){
    # if the stack already exists, the script should update the stack
    . $SCRIPT_UNDER_TEST --output text >test_log

    match_stack_output

    # call it again for update
    . $SCRIPT_UNDER_TEST --output text >test_log

    match_stack_output
}

# tear down
tearDown(){
    pkill moto_server
    echo Test Logs:
    cat test_log
    echo " "
    rm -rf test_log
}

. shunit2
```

Now I run the code on my local machine and the tests pass with no trouble.

Then I push it to gitlab, where the test script gets executed by the gitlab runner, using the python:3.8 image.

The tests fail on the runner, and it seems that the Assert that the patterns match is failing.

I noted that the runner uses grep version 3.3-1, while I have version 3.4 on my local machine, but after looking into it, there is not much difference.

Also, I did take the output that was being produced by the runner and tested it locally trying to match the same regex, and it does match.

I have no clue as to why such a descrepency exists.

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus, I went over shellcheck again and this time it helped me fix it. Thank you, I will post the corrected script as an answer.

Comment: pluse-uno for better than average early poster Q AND the followoing recommendations! Gook luck and keep posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Cyrus, going over to `shellcheck.net` and making the suggested changes worked.

The solution that solved it - 
The following piece of the script:

```
assertTrue "Output Pattern does not match" \
        '$( \
            cat test_log | \
            grep -Eq \
                "^arn:aws:cloudformation:[[:alpha:]]{2}[-](east|west|south|north)-[[:digit:]]:[[:digit:]]*:stack\/bootstrapStack\/[[:alnum:]]*(-[[:alnum:]]*)*$" \
        )'
```

Should have been:

```
assertTrue "Output Pattern does not match" \
        'grep -Eq "^arn:aws:cloudformation:[[:alpha:]]{2}[-](east|west|south|north)-[[:digit:]]:[[:digit:]]*:stack\/bootstrapStack\/[[:alnum:]]*(-[[:alnum:]]*)*$" <test_log'
```

Comment: Would still appreciate if somebody could explain how my local machine could interpret the script correctly. Is this some bash internals stuff?

Comment: If you run the grep by itself, you will be getting the exit codes you expect.  $() will return true always - unless you can't run a subprocess due to resource issues.  Try executing this script in both environments:  `echo $( exit 1)  && echo That was successful`  Despite exiting with an error code, the expression evaluates to true and the `That was successful` gets printed.

Comment: Note that `x=$(exit 1); echo $?` echoes `1`.  When you do `echo $(exit 1); echo $?`, you're getting the status of the `echo` command, which successfully echoed a newline.

Comment: Or simply `(exit 1); echo $? `

Comment: Good stuf above, I would comment that using `grep... < test_log` can be further simplified to `grep .... test_log`. The `<` isn't really needed, and may confuse future maintainers of your script, using a feature that usually implies something else is happening. Keep it simple ;-) Good luck and keep posting.